# How to add session expire time - Grails 4.x

Tags: grails, session-timeout

I've added this part in `application.yml` but it doesn't work.

```
server:
   session:
      timeout: 3600  #seconds
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add

```
server:
    servlet:
        session:
            timeout: 3600
```

Instead of

```
server:
   session:
      timeout: 3600  #seconds
```

Comment: You could also write: server.servlet.session.timeout: 60m. [See](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.server.server.servlet.session.timeout).